# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not replacing placeholder

Tags: spring, weblogic

I want to pass the WSDL url for an internal web service into my Spring beans.xml dynamically, using a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.

Here's the scenario:

My web application is deployed in WebLogic 10.3.
The WSDL url is contained in a properties file that is located *outside* my application (directly under the corresponding domain folder, while my application is inside the *autodeploy* folder). I set the location of this properties file in my domain's *setDomainEnv.cmd* file like below:

```
set JAVA_PROPERTIES=%JAVA_PROPERTIES% %CLUSTER_PROPERTIES% -Dproperty.file.path.config=%DOMAIN_HOME%\Service.properties
```

This is what my Service.properties file contains:

```
Service.WSDL.PATH=http://localhost:8088/mockServiceSoap?WSDL
```

My Spring beans.xml configuration:----

```
<bean id="file.path" class="java.lang.System" factory-method="getProperty">
      <constructor-arg index="0"><value>property.file.path.config</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
       <property name="location" ref="file.path"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceId" class="com.test.service.ServiceImpl">
    <property name="myServiceSoap">
    <ref bean="myService"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"> 
   <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.test.service.ServiceSoap"/> 
   <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="${Service.WSDL.PATH}"/>
</bean>
```

I enabled DEBUG log specifically for PPC and this is what I saw in my application log:

```
INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer 178 - Loading properties file from URL [file:D:/bea10.3/user_projects/domains/my_domain/Service.properties]
```

So, it seems that although the Service.properties file is getting loaded by PPC, the `${Service.WSDL.PATH}` is NOT getting replaced.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, how can I find out if PPC tried replacing the value of the placeholder and with what value? I was hoping the log file would contain that info but there was nothing there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try: ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -- but i don't know it it makes a difference

Comment: Did you get an Application Startup Exception, or is the property just not replaced?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out, that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer needs to be declared first in the application Context file, otherwise there's no guarantee of the load order. It took me a few hours to realize this.

Try moving the "file.path" bean into the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer's location property.